# Magento 2 Production mode still showing Developer Tab

Tags: magento2.4, production-mode

On one of my Magento 2 websites I noticed while in Production mode, the Developer tab is still showing in Stores > Settings -> Configuration > Advanced.

The store seems to be running fine but something has to be wrong as it's not hiding the developer tab.

Has anyone come across this before?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes the `developer` configuration section can still be visible in `production mode` if the `static materialized view files` listed below are not cleaned up.

- `pub\static`
- `var\view_preprocessed`

also `clear the cache`.

For code investigation ,  debug these files

`Magento\Developer\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\WorkflowType`

`Magento\Developer\Model\Config\Backend\WorkflowType` - `afterSave()`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The materialised view files are being cleared completely and the Developer section still appears unfortunately.

Comment: I'm having same behaviour, any ideas?

Comment: Any news regarding same or solution you got